# Why won't Interface Builder change my type of ViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

OK, pulling my hair out! Why doesn't my type `MoreViewController` change when I change the NIB:

[image: See MoreViewController that should be changed when I do pic number two]

[image: Ok I changed it so change IB? WTF?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'MoreViewController' in the nib window is the class name, not the nib name.

If you change the nib name you don't change the class name. Try to name you nibs without 'controller':

```
MoreViewController.m
More.nib
```

This avoids confusion.

---

Also, pulling your hair out is a thing you should not do. It may not grow back again and you'll have bald spots on your head. I think you do not want that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your class; do so from the 4th tab in interface builder. There it will show you the class name, and you can change it to something else.

Comment: Finally! I was wondering why the two other answers were missing this point ^^

Answer (score 0):

The class of the controller bears no relation to the NIB name. Typically one sets them to the same value, but there's no reason why the have to be. You can simply change the NIB name right from that "NIB Name" field you have a screenshot of.